# jQuery script on button is not working

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I think the script is not working because my controller is not running once I press the button in my website. Once I press the button, nothing happens.
The relevant codes are attached.. I'm pretty sure the problem is with my script.

My script:

```
    <script>
    $("#btn_add").click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = '@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart", new {idinput = "IDINPUT", amount = "THEAMOUNTER"})';
        url = url.replace("THEAMOUNTER", $("#amounter").val());
        url = url.replace("IDINPUT", $(this).data("id"));
        window.location.href = url;
    });
</script>
```

the relevant part in the html code:

```
@foreach (var product in Model)
        {

            <figure class="portfolio-item col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <img src="~/images/@product.Picture" class="img-responsive" />
                <div class="product-details">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter amount</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" id="amounter" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a id="btn_add" href="" data-id=@product.Id class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="margin-left:60px">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add to cart
                        </a><br />
```

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html - use a class name instead

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: No errors... Just nothing happens. I could  not follow your first comment.. Do you mean I should replace "#btn_add" with ".btn btn-info btn-lg"?

Comment: He means something to do with this line:  
  
    <a id="btn_add" href="" data-id=@product.Id class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="margin-left:60px">  
  
The browser is reading from what it thinks is a second 'id' attribute.

Comment: Delete the `id="btn_add"`, then use one of you existing class names (or add an additional one - say "add", and use `$(".add").click(...` )

Comment: @user9259829,  No, that is not what I mean at all (and your comment is not correct)

Comment: Oh... I need to stop helping in JQuery. I'm better at normal Javascript tbh

Comment: Put a break point in your script and step through it - is it even being executed (and I assume the script is at the bottom of the page)

Comment: The last line being executed is :  var url = '@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart", new {idinput = "IDINPUT", amount = "THEAMOUNTER"})';

the rest are not

Comment: are you trying to call script in partial view?

Comment: @Infinity I didn't understand what you are asking

Comment: Is your html from question a partial view? and are you putting script tag with this html code?

Comment: @Infinity The html and script are both in the same view

Comment: @TalRofe, this razor code line is executed at server. The question is what the browser is running and what error is raising in console if any. It's not possible to reproduce the error with the information provided, so I'm voting to close. Apart from that, not sure if related but `Url.Action` may be returning something like *"/Cart/AddToCart?idinput=value1&amp;amount=value2"* including `&amp;` instead of `&` as reported here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2077. So you need `var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart", new {idinput = "IDINPUT", amount = "THEAMOUNTER"}))';`

Comment: @TalRofe, when you claim the last line being executed is *"var url = '@Url.Action(..."* and *"nothing happens"* this doesn't make much sense. I guess you just set a breakpoint in Visual Studio and you're breaking at server side, which would be pointless.

Comment: @derloopkat If you'll see my controller in the back-end you will see that once the button is pressed - something need to be happened immidiately.. So I'm 100% sure my controller is fine. Something is wrong with my script.. I also tried your "Raw" instead of action. It has the same result - nothing happens once the button was pressed.

Comment: Maybe there is way to access the controller function without the URL? Just a way to call the controller with the 2 parameters (amount, id)?

Answer (score 2):

give repeated buttons a class instead of using duplicate `ids`. Say `.Mybtn` for instance

```
<a href="" data-id='@product.Id' class="btn btn-info btn-lg Mybtn" style="margin-left:60px">
```

put your click handler in document ready section.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".Mybtn").click(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = '@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart", new {idinput = "IDINPUT", amount = "THEAMOUNTER"})';
            url = url.replace("THEAMOUNTER", $("#amounter").val());
            url = url.replace("IDINPUT", $(this).data("id"));
            window.location.href = url;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with OP's problem (its just invalid html)

Comment: I copied your code into my code.. but problem was the same. Nothing happens in browser once pressed the button..

Comment: @TalRofe, when you do `data-id=@product.Id` in your Html, quotation marks are missing.